# Vue: Cannot find module vue-router or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-router

Bundler vite

Lang ts 5.0.2

Vue3 3.2.47 + Electron

How to solve this
Error:
Vue: Cannot find module  vue-router  or its corresponding type declarations.

Error line:
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router';

tsconfig

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "lib": ["ES2020", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
    "skipLibCheck": true,

    /* Bundler mode */
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",

    /* Linting */
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.d.ts", "src/**/*.tsx", "src/**/*.vue", "electron"],
  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }],
  "paths": {
    "@/*": ["./src/*"]
  },
}
```

package

```
{
  "name": "terror-app",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vue-tsc && vite build && electron-builder",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@element-plus/icons-vue": "^2.1.0",
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "element-plus": "^2.3.8",
    "vue": "^3.2.47",
    "vue-router": "^4.2.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20.4.5",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^4.1.0",
    "electron": "^24.4.0",
    "electron-builder": "^23.6.0",
    "electron-devtools-installer": "^3.2.0",
    "typescript": "^5.0.2",
    "vite": "^4.3.2",
    "vite-plugin-electron": "^0.11.2",
    "vite-plugin-electron-renderer": "^0.14.5",
    "vue-tsc": "^1.4.2"
  },
  "main": "dist-electron/main.js"
}
```

Comment: Just install it using `npm install vue-router`

Comment: It is in the `package.json`. Have you actually _installed_ it, though, @Mirikkingg? Try running `npm install`. If it's a red squiggly, try restarting the TS language server or reloading the project; in VS Code, the command bar has "TypeScript: Restart TS Server" and "TypeScript: Reload Project".

Comment: @Darryl Noakes, thanks, all errors gone!